# How can you stop the Connect/Disconnect sound on WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, audio, kvm-switch

I recently started using a KVM at work, and now every time I switch one of my machines sounds off Windows XP's connected or disconnected device wav file. Is there a way to disable this without muting the whole system (which is what I'm currently doing)?

I went to the Sounds and Audio Devices Properties (from the Control Panel) and then the Sounds tab, and couldn't clear out the sound setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh crap, I realized right after I posted this, you can set each of those sounds to `(None)`.